# Using predicted values to make predictions in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to solve a problem in data.table which requires me to use the value just predicted in the next step of the prediction.

I have the data set up like this, with NA rows generated ready receive the predictions. Each NA is calculated by multiplying the value preceding it by the current parameter

```
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(
  date = as.Date(paste(rep(c(2015, 2016), each = 12, times = 2), 1:12, 1, sep = "-")),
  val = c(rnorm(12, 50, 5), rep(NA, 12)),
  param1 = runif(48),
  cat = rep(c("a", "b"), each = 24)
)
```

I can't do it this way

```
dt[, {
  dt_in <- .SD

  lapply(dt_in[year(date) > 2015, date], function(d){
    dt_sub <- dt_in[date <= d]
    pred <- dt_sub[.N-1, val] * dt_sub[.N, param1]
    dt_in[date == d, val := pred]
  })
} , by = cat]
```

As trying to update the .SD within {} give me the '.SD is locked...' error. My current solution involves breaking the data.table into a list and updating each list item row by row

```
# Create a list of data.tables, one for each category
break_list <- lapply(dt[, unique(cat)], function(c){
  dt[cat == c]
})

l_out <- lapply(break_list, function(dt_in){
# Select the dates requiring prediction
  lapply(dt_in[year(date) > 2015, date], function(d){
    # Subset by date
    dt_sub <- dt_in[date <= d]
    # Prediciton = value from the second to last row * parameter in the last row
    pred <- dt_sub[.N-1, val] * dt_sub[.N, param1]
    # Update data.table
    dt_in[date == d, val := pred]
  })
  dt_in
})

dt_out <- rbindlist(l_out)
```

This works and gives me the desired solution, but it can be slow and feels like I've broken all the data.table rules.  Is there a better way?

Comment: This is quite a bit of code (which is good) but with very little explanation of exactly what you are trying to accomplish.  Could you please show us what the desired result should look like (with an explanation).

Comment: Richard, in 'dt' you will see NAs that need to be replaced with predictions. In dt_out you will find the desired result.  David, I've updated with a bit more info.

Comment: @DavidArenburg not true - one would need to use `dt_in <- copy(.SD)` (data.table copies by reference- if a is locked b<-a will be the same locked table). However one i almost certainly one the wrong path doing something like this...

Comment: @YAK dt_in <- copy(.SD) lets me achieve what I want. Does it have a downside?

Comment: Yes. It makes a copy. And apart from that that solution is almost unreadable... in my opinion, apply should only be used if the calls are independent - very confusing otherwise. I still feel that the question requires some work... using word like "calculate", "dependent" or "iterativly" would make it more general and highlight the core problem. If you put some more effort into it I'll try to give an answer using `data.table::set`

Comment: Yeah forgot about `copy`. Either way, this question is very unclear.

Comment: Indeed, but I could not find any answer on SO to the underlying problem thus I gave an answer...

Comment: Thanks both - if you can point me to a good example of a question I'll endeavor to make sure mine meet your standards in future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking to iteratively update rows of a data.table with values computed from rows updated in a previous iteration. While it is generally better to find an explicit formulation of the problem making the updates independent and it is possible in your case using a helper column holding the `cumprod` of `param1` and a rolling join (`dt[dt[...], ..., roll=TRUE]`) I will show how to do iterative updates of a data.table efficiently using `data.table::set`, as the former is not always easy/possible:

```
setkey(dt, cat, date) # sort by cat first then by date in have the reference value used for each calculation in the row above
val_col_nr <- which(colnames(dt)=="val") # set requires a column number
dt[is.na(val), # we want to compute new values for val where val currently is NA
   # .I is a vector the row numbers (in dt) of each row in .SD
   for (ii in .I) set(dt, i=ii, j=val_col_nr, value=dt[ii,param1]*dt[ii-1L,val]),
   by=cat] # for every 'cat'
```

You can use `identical(dt, setkey(dt_out,cat,date))` to check the result.

Please do also note that it generally a bad idea to use names of base functions (`cat` in your case) as variable names (even in a distinct namespace).

Comment: I'd forgotten `cat` was a base function - thanks for the reminder